# Android TextInputLayout Widget

Tags: android

I am trying to design my application, I have been using androids `widget.TextInputLayout`for the edit text.

The issue is that as soon as the fragment is loaded the hint for the edit text jumps up above the edit text. This is kind of what I want, what I really want is the hint to remain in the edit text until the user clicks on it, at which point the hint will move above the edit.

**Edit Text**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search..."/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
public class SearchRecipes extends ListFragment{

public SearchRecipes() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_recipes, container, false);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Recipe1", "Recipe2", "Recipe3" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

}
```

Comment: Any chance you're actually setting some text into the edit text when the app starts? Maybe sharing the initialization code may help.

Comment: Usually when you have an edittext, it draws focus to it.  You might want to put the focus on another view first.  Then when the user clicks on it, it will have focus and show the hint.

Comment: I added the fragment that is calling the layout containing the edit text above and I amnt pointing the edit text at all. Thanks for the suggestion Kristy I will try and point it at the list or one of the other elements first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `android:focusable = "false"` to your editText and in your `Manifest` add `windowSoftInputMode = "stateHidden"` for the activity. That should work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using the edit text inside a fragment so cant add `windowSoftInputMode = "stateHidden"` to the manifest. But by adding the `android:focusable = "false"` it did stop the hint jumping up but now I cannot enter the `edittext`

Comment: setOnclickListener and enable focus programatically